# Cannot open shared object file libpng12.so.0

Tags: shared-libraries, libpng, quartus, debian-based, parrot-os

I am trying to run Quartus 13.0 in the following machine:

```
parrot 4.18.0-parrot10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-1parrot10 (2018-10-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux.
```

I have finished installing Quartus 13.0 and when I try to execute it I get this error:

```
quartus: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have read all the related questions in stack overflow and other websites but no one worked for me.

When looking for that file, I found it. I have tried to do a hard link but it doesn't work either.  Search results:

```
┌─[pepbd@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $ls -ld $(locate -r libpng.*\.so.*)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 nov 19 17:09 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 -> libpng16.so.16.34.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 210864 jul 10 13:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.34.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18272 oct 14 21:59 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/codec/libpng_plugin.so
```

Comment: You indeed have the libpng but Quartus cannot find them as the names are different: libpng12.so.0 (wanted) versus libpng16.so.16 (available).
You could try a symlink, or install a previous version of the lib.

Comment: I have tried to install the previous version of the lib and it isn't working. And If i do a symlink of libpng16.so.16 it gives an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with Quartus Prime 18 on Ubuntu. This worked for me (run as sudo):

```
wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
  && dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb \
  && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1  This fixed my problem for Ubuntu 22.04 for libpng12 missing